# Custom Shell Prompt in iTerm

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, iterm

I was watching [a Polymer Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrajHIZZbE4&list=TLiTkc1ArHz3syODAxMjAxNg) on youtube and i noticed Rob's iTerm had a different shell prompt. [The '-> crisper-app part'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anzxy.png)

How can I set the same in my iTerm, running on OSX Yosemite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using Bash variables: `PS1`, `PS2`, etc. You simply,

```
export PS1='-> crisper app '
```

Yeah, that settled it.

Answer (score 0):

He is using [Oh My ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and the default `robbyrussell` theme. There are a lot more themes, you can check them out [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)

Comment: Thanks @Peter Foti. After some web digging, i noticed I could achieve that exact functionality by changing my PS1 bash prompt variable. Do I still need to download Oh My Zsh just for that? Or what other advantage does Oh My Zsh offer?